# How to create service class for play Media Player in background in android?

Tags: android

I want to play Media Player in background. Also want to play, stop, pause, next process from main activity in android?
anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MusicService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "MyService";
    public static MediaPlayer mediaplayer;
    String musicfile;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(" ibinder ", "");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", 0).show();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");

        mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", 0).show();
        Log.w(TAG, "onDestroy");
        mediaplayer.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
         Toast.makeText(this,
         "My Service Started :" + intent + " start id :" + startid, 0)
         .show();

         mediaplayer.start();

    }


}
```